# Zookeeper fails to start after Native Library and Intel MKL Parcel Activation in CDH 6.0.0

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, intel-mkl, cloudera-manager

I have 7 Node cluster managed by Cloudera Manager and CDH 6.0.0. I am trying to run matrix multiplication in Spark using a native library which uses BLAS. That is why I have downloaded parcels 1. GPLEXTRAS, and 2. Intel MKL.

However, whenever I activate two parcels across the cluster, the zookeeper failed to start with the following error

```
Error found before invoking supervisord: No parcel provided required tags: set([u'cdh'])
```

What is the reason for failing and how to get rid of this error?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: After activating the parcels, try restarting cm agents (hard!) on all the nodes:

   `$ service cloudera-scm-agent hard_restart_confirmed`

Comment: It is saying: The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl

Comment: oh yeah, its different for different OSes. Please check https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.0/topics/cm_ag_agents.html for your version.

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha. But still no luck. What I have done is activated mkl and mkl_wrapper_parcel. Then stopped all services on the cluster. Next hard restarted scm agent. At last tried to start the services on the cluster...still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Chandan, take a look at this [forum post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/zookeeper-error-during-installation-in-Install-Path-A/td-p/53036/page/3) - the last few posts on it discuss a solution to Zookeeper failing to start properly. It's not a pretty work around, but may help get you going.